# Want to call a 2 get api's using celery in django at sheduled time everyday byitself

Tags: python, django, django-celery

dear community members. I have created a Django project which working totally fine with whatever API I called.

But here I have one small query that there are 2 APIs from which from both APIs while get function is called a defined python script will run.

Now I want to call those two APIs automatically at specific time daily. I tried going with celery. But I don't get how to implement it. I have created `celery.py` in main project folder and `task.py` in app folder with reference of this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/celery-tutorial-using-python). But I'm not getting what the code should be that I need to add in `task.py` to call the APIs daily (with get method).

I watched and gone through several tutorials but not got any yet.It will be very helpful for me if any help with code example. Please help me with good code example as of above scenario.

Comment: check this out: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: I don't have any html files in it. It's only has-(views.py, serializer.py, url.py,and other 2 python files)It based on django restframework. I already went through the link before but here I want to call a Djnagorestframe work api(get method) everyday at specific time...

Comment: This is  a very good tutorial https://testdriven.io/blog/django-celery-periodic-tasks/

Comment: I saw it bro..But it's not solving my need could u please write the example code and share how to call api in celery